# Package pstool Warning: No file containing macro

Tags: psfrag, pstool

I have the following piece of Latex code. I receive this warning:

> Package pstool Warning: No file "epsfigure.tex" or "epsfigure-psfrag.tex" can be found that may contain macros for "epsfigure.eps" on input line 24.

while I have put the .eps figure in the directory. What I should do to get rid of this warning that I see in all my latex files?

Thanks a lot

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite,graphicx,amsmath,amssymb,psfrag,bm}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfsetup{update} % only regenerate pdf files when eps file is newer
\usepackage{pstool}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
  Some text... Suddenly a figure!

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{1\columnwidth}
 \centering
\psfragfig[width=1\columnwidth]{epsfigure}{
\psfrag{1}[c][c][1.]{$w$}
 \psfrag{2}[c][c][1.]{$g$}
 \psfrag{3}[c][c][1.]{$l$}
 \psfrag{4}[c][c][1.]{$s$}
}\caption{}\label{fig:final_1}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth]{test01}
  \caption{} \label{fig:final_3}
  \end{subfigure}
\caption{action.}
\label{fig:final}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Into a directory or a same folder?

Comment: In the same folder

Comment: But the files are .eps or .ps?

Comment: they are .eps figures.

Answer (score 0):

There are afaik know three options

- change from pdflatex to (dvi)latex
- add an empty file `imx/testfig.tex`
- add an empty file `imx/testfig-psfrag.tex`

I assume it is a feature not a bug, you could theoretically use macros in one of `imx/testfig.tex` or `imx/testfig-psfrag.tex`, which might be necesarry, since everything you define in the document will not be accessible in the graphics (e.g. if you define a command in the document you can not use this command in psfragfic in pdflatex (differently to (dvi)latex)).